# Is Qt Jambi development still possible?

Tags: java, eclipse, qt-jambi

I've mostly had GUI development experienced with Qt and C++. Now I'm planning to do some GUI development in Java and had my eyes on Qt Jambi. However, I can't figure out how to get started.

There is relatively new binaries available:
http://qt-jambi.org/downloads

It seems I also need the `Eclipse Integration Plugin`:
http://qt-jambi.org/doc/eclipseintegration

...but the download link is broken, am I missing something? Is Qt Jambi development not possible anymore?

Comment: The Eclipse Integration does not work, but you can use standard Eclipse or whatever IDE you want (IntelliJ), Jambi does not require integration in order to work.

Comment: And yes, our documentation sucks in regards of first use... Basically launching Jambi program means putting qtjambi.jar and qtjambi-native.jar to classpath and your jambi program will run (and compile).

Answer (score 0):

Its possible you just have to find a working link to download it or install a pluginprogram to your browser (depends in your browser)

Comment: This answer is pointless. You should at least provide a working link or explain the situation better

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/qtjambi/qtjambi official clone last updated in 2015.

While many links are now(May 2016) dead, they were archived on archive.is and/or  archive.org/web/

For Qt Designer Manual one can use http://qt.developpez.com/doc/4.7/designer-manual/

The binaries for version 4.3 to 4.5 are available at ftp: //ftp.informatik.hu-berlin.de/pub/Linux/Qt/QT/qtjambi/source/